# TableView - Saving an Individual Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working with Swift and I have a tableView with dynamic prototype cells that have a button on them and I would like it to save the data of an individual cell (Which in this case is one Recipe) so that when that cell's button is touched, the cell would be saved. The individual cell would need to be viewable in another tableView entirely. I am confused as to how I would go about doing this in code as well as whether I should use the User default or core data, I've seen while researching that both should be usable.

**RecipeTableViewController**

```
import UIKit

class RecipeTableViewController: UITableViewController {



    @IBAction func downloadButtonTouched(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    //This is the search term that is imported by segue from SearchViewController.swift

    var searchTermImport: String = ""

    let recipe_API_Call = call_Edamam_API()

    var returned_Recipes = [Hit]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(searchTermImport)
        fetchRecipes()
    }
    //Calls the fetch function in Recipe_API_Caller.swift and attempts to return the results into the empty array "returned_Recipes" of type "Recipe".
    func fetchRecipes(){
        self.returned_Recipes = []
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        let query: [String: String] = [
            "q": searchTermImport,
            "app_id": "b1961989",
            "app_key": "e8caffc800ea5634edbc8b7c9616c61f"
        ]

        recipe_API_Call.fetch(matching: query, completion: {(returned_Recipes) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let returned_Recipes = returned_Recipes{
                    self.returned_Recipes = returned_Recipes
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
                else{
                    print("Fetch Error")
                }
            }
        })
    }

    //Configures the table with the results returned from the "fetchRecipes()" function.
    func configureTable(cell: UITableViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        let returned_Recipe = returned_Recipes[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = returned_Recipe.self.recipe.label

        cell.imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "unnamed")


        let network_task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: returned_Recipe.self.recipe.image){ (data, response, error)
            in
            guard let Image_dest = data else{
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let image = UIImage(data: Image_dest)
                cell.imageView?.image = image
            }
        }
        network_task.resume()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return returned_Recipes.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipeCell", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        configureTable(cell: cell, forItemAt: indexPath)
        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            guard let destinationVC = segue.destination as? RecipeDetailedViewController else{return}
            let selectedRow = indexPath.row
            destinationVC.RecipeName = returned_Recipes[selectedRow].recipe.label
            destinationVC.recipePicture = returned_Recipes[selectedRow].recipe.image
            destinationVC.seeMoreLink = returned_Recipes[selectedRow].recipe.url
            destinationVC.listOfIngredients = returned_Recipes[selectedRow].recipe.ingredientLines
        }
        }
    }
```

This is the code that populates the tableView after the user searches for a term and I want it to save that cell to a "Saved Recipes" TableView after the download button is touched.

[image: The Search Results screen]

I would appreciate any advice you all could provide! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your should add a status property to recipe model, change and save it when clicked, and then in another tableView fetch recipes which status == downloaded and display them.

```
enum RecipeStatus {
   case unDownload, downloaded, paid, finished
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]       
   recipe.status = downloaded
   YourDatabase.save(recipe)
}
```